# What is the node status after a commit in a Galera cluster

Tags: mysql, mariadb, galera

As stated by the Galera documentation, the cluster uses synchronous replication. But looking a bit deeper, there are statements, that Galera is only "virtually" synchronous. On the nodes, a commit has to pass a "certification" instead a physical commit. I really need to understand this part to plan the architecture of an application.

So I like to now which of the following cases would be true if any:

Script A does an `UPDATE` in a transaction taking approximate 5 seconds and a `COMMIT` takes a few seconds either. A Script B follows when Script A is finished immediately, for example with a HTTP-Redirect after HTTP-POST-Request within a second. Script B queries a different node than script A.

1. Script B gets the status before the `UPDATE` because the `UPDATE` still needs around 4 seconds to finish.
2. Script B gets the status after the `UPDATE` because the `COMMIT` finishes when the state of all nodes is synchronous.

Which one would be true if any? Or is the behavior dependent on configuration?

Comment: Depending on "why" the update is slow, the replication of it may be quite fast (row based replication is used).

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54615 seems to cover this.

Comment: @jkavalik On http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54615 is stated, that a small chance of stale data is given? In fact this post was beside the percona faq https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtradb-cluster/5.5/faq.html the cause for my question here. But it seemed for me more of a programming than an admin question. 5 seconds is a bit overrated, might be 50ms, might be because joining different tables or whatever. Important is, that the following script B is faster. But it is my first experience with Galera, perhaps I have the wrong question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sequence of events:

```
-- Node 1:
BEGIN;  (or otherwise start a transaction)
Do some writes
COMMIT;
Node 1 sends the entire transaction (via RBR) to the other nodes.
The other nodes say "OK, there won't be any conflicts".
Node 1 receives the OKs.
Node 1 responds OK to the client.
-- (eventually) on the other nodes:
Actually finish writing the data disk, etc.
```

Note that there is only one roundtrip to each other node, and it happens after `COMMIT`, and before control is returned to the client.
That is Galera's secret sauce.

It is synchronous in that the client gets the OK only after *all* nodes have the data and have agreed that the write will succeed.

It is 'virtual' in that some of the work (usually I/O-intensive) has yet to be done.

A "critical read" is, for example, where a user posts a blog entry, then goes to look at it (but may connect tp a different Slave/Node).  He expects it to be there.  In regular replication, there is no clean way to stall the `SELECT` until the Slave has caught up.  In Galera, `SET wsrep_sync_wait = 31` before doing the `SELECT`.  This will make sure the the "virtual" becomes "real".

The '31' is a bit mask; perhaps you need fewer bits.  See
[wsrep_sync_wait](http://galeracluster.com/documentation-webpages/mysqlwsrepoptions.html#wsrep-sync-wait).

I hope this gives you enough info to figure out what your Node A and Node B will do.

With `autocommit=ON`, and no `BEGIN`, think of a write (eg, `UPDATE`) being `BEGIN; write; COMMIT;`.  Then my list above will still apply.

In my opinion, 5 seconds for a transaction is too long.  I would try to figure out what part of it is the longest and optimize it.

Comment: Thanks, the option `wsrep_sync_wait` is what I searched for and did not know how to ask for :-) And the 5 seconds are just an example, but I know a project with admin tasks where queries take more time and for updating a few 100,000 entries it isn't too much, I guess.

Comment: After testing the option `wsrep_sync_wait` with real word conditions and heavy load, I would discourage the use of this option. Under normal circumstances, it would work, but on heavy load peaks, the galera cluster crashed in our setup. Using a single node for writing and critical tasks and the other nodes for reading tasks outperformed every other setup by length.

Comment: I'm confused.  Are you having your critical reads go to the single Master?

Comment: Yes, we implemented some old code like we used in Master-Slave setups but with a 3 nodes Galera cluster. With that setup the load-test was twice to three times as fast as using galera and `wsrep_sync_wait`. My guess is, that it acts like table locking comparable to the old MyISAM engine.